# would it be consume code smell if i use include twice for the same table?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a specific table that relates more than one table so i use this method to reach them. i wonder is there a better way to do this?

```
    public async Task<ShoppingCart> GetCartWithItems(string phoneNum)
    {
        return await _context.ShoppingCarts.Where(n => n.UserPhoneNum == phoneNum)
            .Include(n => n.Items)
            .ThenInclude(n => n.ShoesList)
            .ThenInclude(n => n.ShoesColors)
            .ThenInclude(n => n.ShoesSizes)
            .Include(n => n.Items)
            .ThenInclude(n => n.ShoesList)
            .ThenInclude(n => n.ShoesImages)
            .FirstAsync();
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of includes, and you probably want a split query. But otherwise is fine, I guess.

Comment: If you are using a recent EF Core, you can also combine levels in one `Include`: `Include(n => n.Items.ShoesList.ShoesColors.ShoesSizes).Include(n => n.Items.ShoesList.ShoesImages)`